# left/inner join shows me 16 entries but i only have 4 in my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

can someone tell me why he shows 16 entries when i already have 4?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d2300/7

i want to show all results where the domain_id is 1 or something else.

What am I doing wrong?

I want to include all 3 tables that I get this record 4 times beacuse in my domain_check table are 4 records

I want:

```
id | domain_id | ssl_check | ssl_orgname 
1  |     1     |    1      |    SSL_TELEKOM
1  |     1     |    0      |    SSL_TELEKOM
1  |     1     |    1      |    SSL_MEDIA
1  |     1     |    1      |    SSL_MEDIA
```

Comment: 4 rows in `ssl_info` for `domain.id = 1`, 4 rows in `domain_check` for `domain.id = 1`, so total rows amount is 4*4=16. Why you are surprised? You may apply `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of simple `SELECT` for to receive unique rows only - the output will contain 4 rows.

Comment: Was just about to say the same as Akina. If you inspect the IDs at the end, you'll see why you get the results you get. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d2300/71 -- `SELECT DISTINCT` *may* be a solution, but that may have performance implications on large datasets, and it might not give you the actual data, but the *distinct* data.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Put what is needed in you post, not just at a link.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: I did not express myself correctly, as many results should be displayed as there are entries in the domain_check. So if 4 entries in domain_check, then i want it like this with join:

domain_id | ssl_check | ssl_organization | date
4 times not 16 times

if i make group by id, then I get 4 records, but then he dont show me the newest records, only the same records like this

id | ssl_org
1  | encrypt
1  |  encrypt

instead of this

id | ssl_org 
1     encrypt
2  |  new encrypt

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all clarfiying information - don't use the comment section for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want the LAST row from domain_check and assuming the id identifies last row then add a condition to the where clause

```
SELECT  domain.id,
            domain_check.domain_id,
            domain_check.ssl_check ,
            ssl_info.domain_id,
            ssl_info.ssl_organisation
FROM domain
INNER JOIN domain_check ON domain_check.domain_id = domain.id
INNER JOIN ssl_info ON domain_check.domain_id = ssl_info.domain_id
WHERE domain.id = 1 and
        domain_check.id = (select max(id) from domain_check s1 where s1.domain_id = domain_check.domain_id);


+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| id | domain_id | ssl_check | domain_id | ssl_organisation |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 |         1 | SSL_TELEKOM      |
|  1 |         1 |         1 |         1 | SSL_TELEKOM      |
|  1 |         1 |         1 |         1 | SSL_MEDIA        |
|  1 |         1 |         1 |         1 | SSL_MEDIA        |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Hey he shows me only the newest records but i want all records. In one of a table is the ssl_check 0.  So in your code there is ssl_check everytime 1

Comment: So whats the logic for that then since the 0 domain check is not the last record by id?

Comment: i want to check records every 15 minutes, and then displayed in a table, if a domain was checked 4 times, then he shows me 16x records. But thats wrong. The Domain was only 4 times checked.

Comment: As the question stands it's not possible to produce the results you want. Reconsider the wording and provide sample data that is representative of your problem . Will delete this answer in 5  mins.

Answer (score -2):

I think this would help you

```
SELECT 
 domain.id,
 domain_check.domain_id,
 domain_check.ssl_check,
 ssl_info.domain_id,
 ssl_info.ssl_organisation
FROM domain
LEFT JOIN domain_check ON domain_check.domain_id = domain.id
LEFT JOIN ssl_info ON domain_check.domain_id = ssl_info.domain_id
WHERE domain.id = 1 group by domain.id
```

Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/uljgzx

Comment: ***Why*** would this be helpful? Please explain your answers instead of posting a code-dump.

Comment: Why you decide that incorrect and non-standard GROUP BY will solve OP's task? Does he tells somewhere that he need one random row? And why you use LEFT joining - it is illogical in this case.

Comment: No thats not help me, if i make group by id then i get the right entries but he dont show the newest records

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid and should raise an exception.

Comment: @MetinSevTHP the newest records have the domain id is 1 as well ?